# cant initialize RecipientEditTextView from android-chips

Tags: android, android-layout, android-chips

I have a problem using [klinker41/android-chips](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips) RecipientEditTextView. Adding it to my layout causes rendering problems because `com.android.ex.chips.RecipientEditTextView` could not be instantiated.

activity_main.xml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.idearobin.michael.chips.MainActivity">

<com.android.ex.chips.RecipientEditTextView
    android:id="@+id/recipientView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.view.WindowManagerImpl cannot be cast to android.view.WindowManagerImpl
at android.view.Window.setWindowManager(Window.java:575)
at android.view.Window.setWindowManager(Window.java:556)
at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:189)
at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:149)
at com.android.ex.chips.RecipientEditTextView.<init>(RecipientEditTextView.java:244)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:458)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:170)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:103)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:168)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:223)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

EDIT:
So far I haven't really gotten around to doing anything with the layout because of the rendering problems with the layout.

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show `RecipientEditTextView ` class code

Comment: I just used this library https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips

Comment: here the source from github https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips/blob/master/library/chips/src/com/android/ex/chips/RecipientEditTextView.java

Comment: show code where using this layout

Comment: Hi, thanks for adding this issue. For me that's another of many examples why not to use third-party libraries. Look at Github, there's more than one issue, so author might know that his library is buggy. Try to implement what you desire using classic Android tools